# Which CMS plugin is best for an existing Rails 3 application with Mongo Mapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system, mongomapper

Can anyone suggest me some good CMS plugin for an existing Rails 3 application with Mongo Mapper

P.S. I am not using Database.yml file for Mongomapper's Initialization, I am using [this method](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started)

and recently I tried to mount my current application(having these gems :'devise','1.1.3'
& 'devise-mongo_mapper',) on [Refinary CMS](http://refinerycms.com/) but it is throwing error that

```
there is no database.yml file
```

so please suggest some useful and easly mountable CMS plugin which are friendly with MongoMapper

any link which is showing a demo for

> "how to mount a current application(ofcourse on MongoMapper) to that particular CMS"

will be more appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refinary is not compatible to MongoMapper. This CMS works only with Sqlite, Mysql or PostgreSQL like explain on his [prerequise guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/installing-refinery-prerequisites).

There are no plugin of CMS with MongoMapper. You can find a CMS doing with Mongo with [Locomotive](http://locomotivecms.com/). But can't be use like engine.

Comment: ohk thanx for the reply so can I mount this locomotive cms to my existing application ?? and how can I change its default route ?? 

Actually what I want is : I want the functionality of that CMS to work on a manually made admin management under CMS tab so how to do this ??  I hope U'll reply and help me to solve this issue !!! :)